# How to add form tag for a checbox attribute that is stored as a datetime in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, form-helpers

Let's say that I have a table called `advertisements`. I need to add a field for it so people can flag it as `active` or `inactive`. I can add a `boolean` field called inactive and that's a straight forward approach.

There is another approach where I can create a field `inactive` with datatype of `datetime`. This not only tells me whether an advertisement is active/no, but also tells when it was deactivated. So if the value is null, it's active and if it's a timestamp, it was deactivated at that time in the past.

The problem, however, is adding it to the form helper. 
For a checkbox implementation, Rails suggests following:

```rb
= f.check_box :inactive, { class: 'something' }
```

This works fine with the datatype as `boolean` in db. 
How do I make this work with `datetime` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. So with the `check_box` helper you can specify when a checkbox should be displayed as `checked` and you can also specify the value to assign when someone checks the box.

I did this

```rb
= f.check_box :inactive, { class: 'something', checked: f.object.inactive.present? }, f.object.inactive.nil? ? DateTime.now : f.object.inactive
```

The last part `DateTime.now` is the value that gets assigned when a user checks the box. This way you can save a DateTime value using a checkbox implementation. The presence of value helps you determine whether the checkbox should be checked or not when you display the form.

The only caveat with this approach is the accuracy of the value. User might submit the form after few mins/hours of opening the form. If it's important for you to capture the right value, you can use JS to assign the exact value or have the logic in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have a method for permitting parameters

```
def advertisment_params
  params.require(:advertisement).permit(:inactive)
end
```

By altering the method to be

```
def advertisment_params
  params[:advertisement][:inactive] = params[:advertisement][:inactive] == "0" ? nil : @advertisement.nil? ? DateTime.now.to_s(:db) : @advertisement.inactive
  params.require(:advertisement).permit(:inactive)
end
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
= f.check_box :inactive, checked: form.object.inactive.present?,  { class: 'something' }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me half way through. It helps with the logic to show a checkbox checked/unchecked. It still needs to address the logic to set the value when you check the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on implementing support for a boolean param to datetime transformation done at the controller level. This addresses the issue in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436824/1006439) where the timestamp is stale due to the datetime being generated in the edit view instead at the time of PUT/PATCH.

Code is written to work with Rails 6. YMMV on other versions.

First you'll want the timestamp column on your table. Let's call the model `Resource` and the table `resources`. Add the datetime field `inactive_at` in a migration.

```rb
def change
  add_column :resources, :inactive_at, :datetime
end
```

I am assuming in the controller, the resource is instantiated and assigned to `@resource`.

In the view form, you'll want the following check box line inside your form helper block.

```
f.check_box :inactive, checked: @resource.inactive_at?
```

The `checked: @resource.inactive_at?` sets the default value of the check box. We are going to use the param `inactive` to host the boolean information of whether to update `inactive_at`.

In your controller, you'll want the following. For brevity, I excluded details if the controller is inheriting a parent class, the actions, and the existence of other params.

```rb
class ResourceController
  private

  def resource_params
    translate_inactive_param

    params.require(:resource).permit(:inactive_at)
  end

  def translate_inactive_param
    return if params[:resource][:inactive_at].present?
    return if changing_inactive_at_is_not_requested?
    return if touching_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_present?
    return if removing_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_blank?

    params[:resource][:inactive_at] = cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) ? Time.current : nil
  end

  def changing_inactive_at_is_not_requested?
    inactive_param.nil?
  end

  def touching_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_is_already_present?
    cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) && @resource.inactive_at?
  end

  def removing_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_blank?
    !cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) && @resource.inactive_at.blank?
  end

  def inactive_param
    params.dig(:resource, :inactive)
  end

  def cast_to_boolean(value)
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)
  end
end
```

I will go over each method.

```rb
def resource_params
  transform_inactive_param

  params.require(:resource).permit(:inactive_at)
end
```

This is the method with [strong parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Before returning the strong parameters, the `inactive` param with boolean'ish value will be translated into a datetime object for `inactive_at`.

For the boolean'ish value of `inactive`, a Rail's form helper will output `"0"` for `false` and `"1"` for `true`.

For [typecasting in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html), the following are considered falsey: `false, 0, "0", :"0", "f", :f, "F", :F, "false", :false, "FALSE", :FALSE, "off", :off, "OFF", :OFF`

For truthy, it is any value other than `nil`.

For this example, we will assume an undefined `inactive` in the params or assigned `nil` value to mean no change to `inactive_at` is requested. This is a reasonable assumption given if the request omits `inactive` from the request payload.

```rb
  def translate_inactive_param
    return if params[:resource][:inactive_at].present?
    return if changing_published_at_is_not_requested?
    return if touching_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_present?
    return if removing_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_blank?

    params[:resource][:inactive_at] = cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) ? Time.current : nil
  end
```

This method translates the `inactive` param to `inactive_at` param.

The guard clause pattern is used here. There are a few conditions we want the translation to skip.

- `params[:resource][:inactive_at].present?` — We prioritize the already present `inactive_at` param over `inactive`. Useful if `resource_params` is being called multiple times in the controller.
- `changing_published_at_is_not_requested?` — If the `@resource.inactive_at` is already present and `inactive` param is truthy, then we don't want to touch the field. I made the assumption it isn't a requirement to update the timestamp.
- `removing_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_blank?` — If `@resource.inactive_at` is already blank and `inactive` param is falsey, then there is no need to translate to `inactive_at` param.

If none of these conditions are met, then the translation will proceed.

A ternary is used to determine if the translated value to be assigned to the `inactive_at` params will be a timestamp or `nil`. Casting is used to translate the `inactive_param` into a boolean.

```rb
def changing_inactive_at_is_not_requested?
  inactive_param.nil?
end
```

Self explanatory by method name. Pulled into a method to give clarity on what it does by giving it a descriptive method name.

```rb
def touching_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_is_already_present?
  cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) && @resource.inactive_at?
end
```

Self explanatory by method name. Pulled into a method to give clarity on what it does by giving it a descriptive method name.

```rb
def removing_inactive_at_is_requested_and_inactive_at_is_already_blank?
  !cast_to_boolean(inactive_param) && @resource.inactive_at.blank?
end
```

Self explanatory by method name. Pulled into a method to give clarity on what it does by giving it a descriptive method name.

```rb
def inactive_param
  params.dig(:resource, :inactive)
end
```

Access the value of `inactive` param from in `params`. Since this is used a few times I extracted it out into a method.

```rb
def cast_to_boolean(value)
  ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)
end
```

Cast "boolean" values, in particular from Rails form helper or any request done via HTTP. Rails has built in classes which typecast various objects. The [`ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html) is the one we are interested in.

Edit:

As an added bonus, here is a request test made in RSpec which tests the functionality. A controller test may be more appropriate ‍♂️

I will not go line-by-line to explain it, so I'll leave it up to the reader to interpret the test.

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher(:not_change, :change)

RSpec.describe 'PATCH/PUT /resources/:id/edit', type: :request do
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

  shared_examples 'update `inactive_at` using parameter `inactive`' do
    describe '`inactive` parameter' do
      let(:resource) { Resource.create(inactive_at: nil) }
      let(:params) { { resource: { inactive: nil } } }
      subject { -> { resource.reload } }
  
      it { is_expected.to(not_change { resource.inactive_at }) }
  
      context 'when `inactive` key is form value falsey "0"' do
        let(:params) { { resource: { inactive: '0' } } }
  
        it { is_expected.to(not_change { resource.inactive_at }) }
      end
  
      context 'when `inactive` key is form value truthy "1"' do
        let(:params) { { resource: { inactive: '1' } } }
  
        around { |example| freeze_time { example.run } }
  
        it { is_expected.to(change { resource.inactive_at }.to(Time.current)) }
      end
  
      context 'when `inactive_at` is present in the resource' do
        let(:resource) { Resource.create(inactive_at: 1.year.ago) }
  
        it { is_expected.to(not_change { resource.inactive_at }) }
  
        context 'and when `inactive` key is form value falsey "0"' do
          let(:params) { { resource: { inactive: '0' } } }
  
          it { is_expected.to(change { resource.inactive_at }.to(nil)) }
        end
  
        context 'and when `inactive` key is form value truthy "1"' do
          let(:params) { { resource: { inactive: '1' } } }
  
          it { is_expected.to(not_change { resource.inactive_at }) }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'PATCH' do
    before do
      patch resource_path(resource), params: params
    end

    include_examples 'update `inactive_at` using parameter `inactive`'
  end

  describe 'PUT' do
    before do
      put resource_path(resource), params: params
    end

    include_examples 'update `inactive_at` using parameter `inactive`'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Active Record provides [query methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activerecord/lib/active_record/base_rb.html) for each attribute in your model, they are named after attribute name ending with question mark (eg. for `model.name` attribute there is `model.name?`) that responded with false when attribute is empty and true otherwise. Additionally, when dealing with numeric values, a query method will return false if the value is zero.

AR query methods will give you a getter for your `inactive?` flag, you need to add setter to allow saving changes to `inactive?` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

To track deactivate time

Add a column `deactivated_at` `datetime`

```
add_column :advertisements, :deactivated_at, :datetime
```

in form

```
<%= form.text_field :deactivated_at, class: "add-datetimepicker" %>
```

add a datetimepicker on the field

[bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

[datetimepicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)